# Applying Ken Burns effect on an AVMutableVideoComposition

Tags: ios, image, video, avfoundation

I'm working on an app that creates videos from a series of images, using AVMutableVideoComposition. I wanted to add a "Ken Burns" effect on the images, and I created the effect applying transforms to the main AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction object using the method "setTransformRampFromStartTransform:toEndTransform:timeRange:"

It works, but the scale effect gives an ugly result... it looks like refreshes of the frames are visible... it is like an old computer that cannot keep up the frame rate of the video... I don't really know how to explain this :)

Do you think there is a better way to achieve the result? For example, using AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool?

Can I add animations to the single video tracks in the compositions?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you add ken burn effect on video or images? because on image you should use AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool